# Transform with tensor product

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, convolution

I'm new to Laplace and Fourier transforms when convolution is involved, and I've never seen an example involving a tensor product. I'd like to see how the Fourier transforms of the following would look:

$\frac{\partial (a(x,t) \bigotimes b(x,t))}{\partial x}$

Comment: if this is new, consider the 1-dimensional case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Comment: @user1952009 I've edited my question to be more specific

Comment: take the Fourier transform for $x$ to get $(2 i \pi f) \left(A_{ij}(.,t) \ast B_{kl})(.,t) \right)(f)$. the **tensor** product changes nothing, it stays a list of normal product

Comment: @user1952009 do you know of a good online resource which works with Laplace and Fourier transforms with such applications and examples? I know wikipedia gives you the formulas and proofs, but it's easier to learn by example than to try and apply formulas and proofs you're not use to working with. Thanks for your insight